# Не срабатывают отдельные поисковые строки

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, я нуб и первый поиск мой пишу, вообще сделал проверку инпутов и вывод из базы
. Помогите сделать, чтобы по отдельно каждому полю выводилось.

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$id_s = $_POST['id'];
$group_s = $_POST['group'];
$number_s = $_POST['number'];
$famely_s = $_POST['famely'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE id = '$id_s'  OR famely = '$famely_s'");

if ($search) {
if($group_s == "" OR $number_s == "" OR $famely_s == "") {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE id = '$id_s'");
} elseif ($number_s == "" OR $famely_s == "") {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE id = '$id_s' group = '$group_s'");
} elseif ($famely_s == "") {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE id = '$id_s' nomber = '$number_s' group = '$group_s'");
} 
elseif($id_s == "" OR $number_s == "" OR $famely_s == "") {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE group = '$group_s'");
} elseif ($id_s == "" OR $group_s == "" OR $number_s == "") {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE famely = '$famely_s'");
}

}  else {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file ")  or die ( mysql_error() );
}
```

Comment: `WHERE id = '$id_s' group = '$group_s'`

Подобные конструкции должны раздеяться ключевыми словами OR или AND

Comment: Аммм, они срабатывают ))) позже поправлю, а вот 
elseif($id_s == "" OR $number_s == "" OR $famely_s == "") {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE group = '$group_s'");
Не пашет

Comment: group - зарезервированное слово в SQL, его надо брать в обратные апострофы (на той же клавише, что и тильда)

Comment: Щас вообще не чего не понял о_О

Comment: Тоже не срабатывает

    elseif ($id_s == "" OR $group_s == "" OR $number_s == "") {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE famely = '$famely_s'");
    }